# Is it possible to reference the output of an IronPython project from within a c# project?

Tags: c#, python, assemblies, ironpython

I would like to build a code library in IronPython and have another C# project reference it. Can I do this? How?

Is this just as simple as building the project and referencing the dll? Is there any conflict with the dynamic aspect of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no way to build [CLS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a7a7h3.aspx)-compliant assemblies from IronPython. The `pyc` tool will generate a DLL from Python code, but it's really only useful from IronPython.

If you want to use IronPython from a C# app, you'll have to use the [hosting interfaces](http://www.ironpython.info/index.php/Hosting_IronPython_2) ([gory details](http://dlr.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Docs%20and%20specs)). You could also check out [IronPython in Action](http://www.amazon.ca/Ironpython-Action-Michael-Foord/dp/1933988339/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1252085531&sr=1-1), which describes the hosting process quite well.

Comment: So in iron-python you can add a reference to an assembly and call a method or use a class no problem. You really can't do it the other way a around? :(

Comment: Unfortunately, no. That's a big reason why C# 4 is getting the dynamic keyword; it will make these scenarios much easier.